# Как в объект добавить верстку, чтоб JSON.parse не выдавал ошибки

Tags: javascript, json

Есть такого рода объект:

```
var data = '{ \
 "obj": [ \
        { "id": 1, "coord": [53.831235, 27.175426], "country": "<div class=\"nameClass\"><\/div>", "city": "Москва", "address": "улица Довженко, 1с1" },\
        { "id": 2, "coord": [53.918879, 27.906016], "country": "Россия", "city": "Москва", "address": "улица Довженко, 2" }\
    ]\
}';
```

После перевожу в json `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Но выдает ошибку:

> Unexpected token < in JSON

.
Как добавить в объект верстку с классами так чтоб json не ругался?

Comment: Так проблема не  классах верстки.....Зачем столько обратных слэшей? Я бы лично на них ругался. Ибо в таком виде, конечно же, он не валиден

Comment: В общем у вас 5 ненужных обратных слэшей. почините это и будет работать..... для валидации можете кинуть json сюда http://json.parser.online.fr и убрать всё лишнее

Comment: я думал экранировать кавычи класса но оно не работает а как то экранировать кавычки нужно так как у объекта есть кавычки. а слэши которые в конце строки это чтоб можно было писать на новой строке. ошибка лишь в добавлении верстки с классом, как это сделать?

Comment: Еще раз повторю `проблема не классах верстки` и не в слешах в районе классов..... у вас 5 слэшей совсем в других, абсолютно непонятных местах....... `слэши которые в конце строки это чтоб можно было писать на новой строке` - для этого придумали знаки конкатенации

Comment: те слеши ни при чем, если вместо верстки вставить просто текст в кавычках все работает, те слеши для того чтоб можно было писать код на разных строках

Comment: Алексей, так вы можете написать как правильно?

Comment: Вместо тех слешей, которые якобы должны позволять код с новой строки вам надо писать закрывающую кавычку (одинарную) и знак конкатенации, а на новой строке опять писать открывающую кавычку (одинарную)

Comment: Сделал, как вы написали ошика не исчезла http://prntscr.com/cky1t2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = '{ \
 "obj": [ \
        { "id": 1, "coord": [53.831235, 27.175426], "country": "\<div class=\'nameClass\'>\<\/div\>", "city": "Москва", "address": "улица Довженко, 1с1" },\
        { "id": 2, "coord": [53.918879, 27.906016], "country": "Россия", "city": "Москва", "address": "улица Довженко, 2" }\
    ]\
}';

var json = JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: Точно в чель, про экранирование < я и забыл, так работает, спасибо!

Comment: @Karalahti, присмотрись получше, ошибку исправило не _экранирование <_, а замена кавычек вокруг атрибута на одинарные

Comment: Стоило все-таки указать, что именно решает проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема заключается в неправильном экранировании кавычек.

Добавляя `\` перед кавычкой - экранирование происходит **в текущей** строке.

*JSON.parse* же пытается разобрать получившуюся строку, в которой кавычки уже **не экранированы**.

Одним из решений может быть простая смена кавычек для атрибутов на одинарные, так как html позволяет использовать любой тип кавычек.

Еще один вариант: экранировать в исходной строке не кавычку, а сам слэш, тогда, при разборе JSON.parse, этот слэш будет экранировать следующую за ним кавычку и проблема пропадет.

Пример:

```js
var data = '{ \
 "obj": [ \
        { "id": 1, "coord": [53.831235, 27.175426], "country": "<div class=\\"nameClass\\">123<\/div>", "city": "Москва", "address": "улица Довженко, 1с1" },\
        { "id": 2, "coord": [53.918879, 27.906016], "country": "Россия", "city": "Москва", "address": "улица Довженко, 2" }\
    ]\
}';

console.log(JSON.parse(data));

d.innerHTML = JSON.parse(data).obj[0].country;
```

```css
#d {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
}
.nameClass {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div id="d"></div>
```